# numpy.sin function in degrees?

Tags: python, math, numpy, trigonometry

I'm working on a problem that has to do with calculating angles of refraction and what not. However, it seems that I'm unable to use the numpy.sin() function in degrees. I have tried to use numpy.degrees() and numpy.rad2deg().

```
numpy.sin(90)

numpy.degrees(numpy.sin(90))
```

Both return ~ 0.894 and ~ 51.2 respectively.

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 96, accepted):

You don't want to convert *to* degrees, because you already have your number (90) in degrees.  You need to convert 90 *from* degrees to radians, and you need to do it *before* you take the sine:

```
>>> np.sin(np.deg2rad(90))
1.0
```

(You can use either `deg2rad` or `radians`.)

Answer (score 20):

Use the `math` module from the standard Python library:

```
>>> math.sin(math.radians(90))
```

Comment: One problem would be that it isn't vectorized while the numpy solution above is. But, that comes down to if you are using numpy or not...

Comment: What do you mean vectorized? They both return the same number.

Comment: But the numpy functions will take a numpy array and return an array.  If you do lots of math, you should check out numpy...

Comment: Yeah, NumPy is great, but sometimes it is better to avoid dependencies and go with the standard library. ^^

Answer (score 3):

You can define the following symbols to work in degrees:

```
sind = lambda degrees: np.sin(np.deg2rad(degrees))
cosd = lambda degrees: np.cos(np.deg2rad(degrees))
print(sind(90)) # Output 1.0
```

Answer (score 2):

As a warning, none of these answers will work for very large inputs.
`numpy`'s `deg2rad` function simply multiplies the argument by pi/180.
The source for this is [here](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/main/numpy/core/src/npymath/npy_math_internal.h.src) (at the C level).

Imprecision in this value will result in horrible error. For example:

```py
import numpy

def cosd(x):
    return numpy.cos(numpy.deg2rad(x))

print(cosd(1.0E50)) # Prints -0.9999338286702031
```

Let's try this in C with some standard library tricks.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>

#define cosd(x) cos(fmod((x), 360.0) * M_PI / 180.0)

int main(void)
{
    const double x = 1.0E50;
    printf("%f\n", cosd(x));
    return 0;
}
```

This prints out `0.766044`, so our `cosd` function in Python is off by about 2, when the function is bounded between -1 and 1!

It seems `numpy` has a mod function. Let's duplicate this C routine using that.

```py
import numpy

def cosd(x):
    return numpy.cos(numpy.deg2rad(numpy.mod(x, 360.0)))

print(cosd(1.0E50)) # 0.7660444431189778
```

And all is well.

Answer (score 0):

Multiplying by `pi/180` perform the conversion from degrees to radians. So, `np.sin(90*np.pi/180)` works as well.

Answer (score 0):

FIY. SciPy provides the sin function which accepts degrees:
https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.sindg.html#scipy.special.sindg

```
In [2]: import scipy.special as special

In [3]: special.sindg(90)
Out[3]: 1.0
```